# Does xmpp Resource Change?

Tags: xmpp

I'm writing an app which communicates with clients via XMPP. I want to be able to use the users existing xmpp account (they all have google ID's) but I don't want my messages to appear in their regular IM stream.

I'm thinking that when my client pairs with the server it could use a custom resource id eg Fred.Bloggs@gmail.com/MYCUSTOMID then I can always send messages to that ID with the resource tag.

Is this the best approach, are Resource ID's tied to a specific install of a client or should they change on a per session basis?

Answer (score 1):

Google will modify any resource you give it by adding a random identifier to the end.

If you're writing both the sender and the receiver, try using an XMPP extension:

```
<message to="fred.bloggs@gmail.com">
  <x xmlns='http://my.domain.example.com/my_extension'>stuff</x>
</message>
```

If you need to be able to tell which of the resources is your client, try [XEP-0115](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html).